# Read a file from another machine from the server

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, security, applet

Are there any ways to read a text file of a User machine from the server via JavaScript/Code Behind (C#)?
*(Server and User is from two different machines. Server will try to read a text file from User machine)*

As part of security, system requires to retrieve the serial number of the machine being used. Currently, it is being done via an applet, who reads the User file and returns it to the server for validation. Are there any ways can this same process be done without using an applet?

Thank you.

Comment: It would be pretty terrible on the security front if you could, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

This will be a great vulnerability, probably you can do some tricks to do that and convince the user to install some plugins/software that do that (anyway the client will send the data to the server and not vice versa). but this will be very dangerous for your user.
bottom line - this is not recommended and shouldn't be done.